# Solve coupled equations in the steady state

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve 16 coupled differential equations in the steady state.
Among the answers, I only require two of the answers. But the Mathematica does not show me the answers in detail!!!

Can anybody please help me?

My code is as follows:
How can I get only the answer of v33 and v44 in details?

```
equil = {2 (-\[Kappa] + \[Lambda] Cos[\[Phi]]) v11 + (\[CapitalDelta] \
+ \[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) (v12 + v21) + 
    g (v14 + v41) + \[Kappa]/
     2 (1 + 2 \[ScriptCapitalN] + 
       2 \[ScriptCapitalM] Cos[\[Theta]]), -2 \[Kappa] v12 + (\
\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) v22 + (-\[CapitalDelta] + \
\[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) v11 + 
    g (v42 - 
       v13) + \[Kappa] \[ScriptCapitalM] Sin[\[Theta]], (-\[Kappa] - \
\[Gamma] + \[Lambda] Cos[\[Phi]]) v13 + (\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] \
Sin[\[Phi]]) v23 + 
    g (v12 + 
       v43) + \[Delta] v14, (-\[Kappa] - \[Gamma] + \[Lambda] Cos[\
\[Phi]]) v14 + (\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) v24 + 
    g (v44 - 
       v11) - \[Delta] v13, (-\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] \
Sin[\[Phi]]) v11 + (\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) v22 - 
    2 \[Kappa] v21 + 
    g (v24 - 
       v31) + \[Kappa] \[ScriptCapitalM] Sin[\[Theta]], (-\
\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) (v12 + v21) - 
    2 (\[Kappa] + \[Lambda] Cos[\[Phi]]) v22 - 
    g (v23 + v32) + \[Kappa]/
     2 (1 + 2 \[ScriptCapitalN] - 
       2 \[ScriptCapitalM] Cos[\[Theta]]), (-\[CapitalDelta] + \
\[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) v13 + (-\[Kappa] - \[Gamma] - \[Lambda] Cos[\
\[Phi]]) v23 + 
    g (v22 - 
       v33) + \[Delta] v24, (-\[Delta] + \[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) v14 + \
(-\[Kappa] - \[Gamma] - \[Lambda] Cos[\[Phi]]) v24 - 
    g (v34 + v21) - \[Delta] v23,
   (-\[Kappa] - \[Gamma] + \[Lambda] Cos[\[Phi]]) v31 + (\
\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) v32 + 
    g (v21 + 
       v34) + \[Delta] v41, (-\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] \
Sin[\[Phi]]) v31 + (-\[Kappa] - \[Gamma] - \[Lambda] Cos[\[Phi]]) v32 \
+ g (v22 - v33) + \[Delta] v42, -2 \[Gamma] v33 + 
    g (v23 + v32) + \[Delta] (v34 + v43) + \[Gamma]/
     2 (1 + 2 m), -2 \[Gamma] v34 + 
    g (v24 - v31) + \[Delta] (v44 - 
       v33), (-\[Kappa] - \[Gamma] + \[Lambda] Cos[\[Phi]]) v41 + (\
\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] Sin[\[Phi]]) v42 + 
    g (v44 - 
       v11) - \[Delta] v31, (-\[CapitalDelta] + \[Lambda] \
Sin[\[Phi]]) v41 + (-\[Kappa] - \[Gamma] - \[Lambda] Cos[\[Phi]]) v42 \
- g (v12 + v43) - \[Delta] v32, -2 \[Gamma] v43 + 
    g (v42 - v13) + \[Delta] (v44 - v33), -2 \[Gamma] v44 - 
    g (v14 + v41) - \[Delta] (v34 + v43) + \[Gamma]/2 (1 + 2 m)};

Solve[equil == 0, {v11, v12, v13, v14, v21, v22, v23, v24, v31, v32, 
  v33, v34, v41, v42, v43, v44}]
```

Comment: After a few minutes of waiting I could get a solution for all unknowns: `{b, A} = CoefficientArrays[
  equil == 0, {v11, v12, v13, v14, v21, v22, v23, v24, v31, v32, v33, v34, v41, v42, v43, v44}]` followed by `sol=LinearSolve[A, -b]`followed by `sol[[11]]` and `sol[[16]]`. However, they are too long (with `LeafCount` being 730546 and 384903, respectively), and supposedly not very useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful response.